# Converting op-amp circuit into inverting op-amp, single supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, audio, single-supply-op-amp

I'm currently trying to build an inverting op-amp with single 12 V supply for audio applications.

The circuit below is the one that worked super well with 12-0-12 (had low noise and low distortion), and now I want to convert it to a single-supply amp with inverting input.

I'm very new to op-amps and couldn't figure out a satisfactory solution on how to do so.

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how much power you want on the output.  ±12V = 24Vpp. Whereas 0-5V = 5Vpp (peak to peak).  That won't be very loud.

Comment: Why don't you use a negative supply generator circuit.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider the LM386 audio amplifier. It works with a single supply, and requires very few parts.

Comment: @Aaron 12Vpp in my case is enough

Comment: @Andyaka well I'm trying to build a very compact amplifier and a center tapped transformer with rectifier etc would kinda defy the purpose of my design

Comment: No, why don't you use a negative supply generator like the ICL7662.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this chip, I will definetly look into it!

Comment: @James so you mean C5 between Feedback Loop and GND parallel to R7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTfZSH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So all you need to do is add a voltage divider (R2, R3) and C1, C2 capacitors to your project.

Or the inverting version

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffgr9P.png)</sup>

Comment: The op wants an inverting amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka Oops, I didn't notice this.

Comment: Thank you, so I just connect the non-inverting input to the divider and the input to the feedback loop? What would happen with R3, R5 and C5 from my schematic?

Comment: @MarvinW Yes, exactly you need a voltage divider at non-inverting input plus some large bypass capacitor. And the input via coupling capacitor (C3) to R7 (in your schematic). R5 and C5 are not needed in inverting configuration. And use R3 as a pull-down resistor for the C3 capacitor.

Comment: Okay will try that, thank you very much for your help

Comment: You might want to increase RF to 12k to get a similar gain to the non-inverting version.

Comment: @G36 what about R7 in my schematic? Do I need it in inverting configuration or can I remove it?

Comment: @MarvinW No, you cannot remove R7. R7 equals R5 (2.2k) in my second schematic.